# Captcha auto-change on input

Tags: reactjs, captcha, antd

I'm working on a form with captcha using reactjs and antdesign, My problem is when I type on other fields, the captcha code change.

Hope you understand me..

Thanks

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4rr7qm6mx7)

```
<FormItem>
    <Input
    prefix={<Icon type="key" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
    type="captcha"
    placeholder="captcha"
    addonAfter={<Captcha />}
    />
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ReactJS`: `re-rendering` can be `disabled` via [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), by `returning` `false`.

See below for a practical example.

See [this fork of your CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3yp865v1qp) for a working solution.

```
// Captcha.
class Captcha extends Component {

  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <div className="Captcha">
      <NumberList />
    </div>
  )

  // Should Component Update.
  shouldComponentUpdate = () => false

}
```